# Angular call web api to login token based with owin

Tags: angular, token, owin

I'm at the beginning with angular and I have a problem with the call to authenticate my web api.
My web api use Owin and I've already used it with an old asp site.
I call whith ajax without problems:

$.ajax({url: _TokenApi, 
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Authorization": _CLIENTAUTH
                },
                data: body, 
                complete: function(result) {

```
            },
            success: function(result) {
                sessionStorage.setItem(_GLOBALPREFIX+'xms_token',result.access_token);
                xms_Login_ok(dataLogin);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                 xms_alert('warning', 'Attenzione', 'Token non recuperato correttamente');
            },
        });
```

I want to make the same call with angular,I found an example done this way

UserAuthenticationOriginal(UserName: string,Password: string):Observable{
    let credentials='username=' +UserName  + '&password=' +Password +'&grant_type=password';
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded','No-Auth':'True' });
   return this.http.post(this.ApiUrl+'token',encodeURI(credentials),{headers:reqHeader});
 }

this function arrives at the web api, but obviously it doesn't authenticate because I called with: 
'No-Auth': 'True'

I tried to replace with
 headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.set("Authorization", 'BASIC XXXXXXX');
    let credentials='username=' +UserName  + '&password=' +Password +'&grant_type=password'; 
    let a= this.http.post(this.ApiUrl+'token',encodeURI(credentials),{headers:headers});

But I have a Error:
ERROR TypeError: "this.api.UserAuthentication(...) is undefined"

and does not make any calls to the web api

Answer (score 0):

my problem was in the interceptor.ts. this work:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   if(window.sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')!=null){
        request = request.clone({
            headers:request.headers.set("Authorization","Bearer " +window.sessionStorage.getItem('userToken'))  
                                    .set("Content-type", "application/json") 

          });

    }else{
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
   }
   return next.handle(request);
}
```